# Two login forms in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I've been wondering how could i make two login forms in laravel 5 for a while... The reason of this is because i have a multi-site project, i've got the admin site, and the public site in one project.

I've grouped the routes so the admin routes answer to a domain and public routes answer to another domain like this:

```
Route::group(array( 'domain' => 'restaurant.com', 'namespace' => 'Public' ), function () {
    //some routes
});

Route::group(array( 'domain' => 'restaurant.net', 'namespace' => 'Admin' ), function () {
    //some routes
});
```

I've also created custom routes for authentication in each group of routes like this (this ones are for Public):

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);

Route::get( '/register' , [
    'as' => 'publicRegister' ,
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister'
] );

Route::post( '/registrar' , [
    'as' => 'publicPostRegister' ,
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister'
] );

Route::get( '/login' , [
    'as' => 'publicLogin' ,
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin'
] );

Route::post( '/login' , [
    'as' => 'publicPostLogin' ,
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin'
] );

Route::get( '/logout' , [
    'as' => 'publicLogout' ,
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout'
] );
```

I've also created the Auth folder with it's controllers ('`AuthController`', '`PasswordController`') in each parent folder, my controllers are like this:

```
app    
|---Http
    |---Controllers
        |----------Public
        |          |---Auth
        |          |    |---AuthController
        |          |    |---PasswordController
        |          |--- ...
        | 
        |----------Admin
                  |---Auth
                  |    |---AuthController
                  |    |---PasswordController
                  |--- ...
```

And so for the views i've got separate Auth views like this:

```
resources
    |---views
        |----------Public
        |          |---Auth
        |          |    |---login.blade.php
        |          |    |---password.blade.php
        |          |    |---register.blade.php
        |          |    |---reset.blade.php
        |          |--- ...
        | 
        |----------Admin
                   |---Auth
                   |    |---login.blade.php
                   |    |---password.blade.php
                   |    |---register.blade.php
                   |    |---reset.blade.php
                   |--- ...
```

In my models the users table has a **type** column that will filter users from Public or Admin site.
The main question here is: How could i make two login forms for my project? 
What i would like is that Public Users couldn't log into the Admin site and viceversa.

What i've tried so far is override the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` functions like `getLogin`, `getRegister` and also variables like `$loginPath`, `$redirectTo` but when calling `publicPostLogin`(checkout routes) in the login form of Public that has as action `{{ route('publicPostLogin') }}` it just don't works...

Comment: You can make changes to the `Authenticate` and `RedirectIfAuthenticated` Middleware to check for the **type** column. You will also want to create two new middlewares for the admin section.

Comment: Will there be one Middleware for each Public and Admin?

Comment: Yeah, I usually create a `Admin` directory in the `Middleware` directory and just copy both middleware in there and add the correct namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you hear about [Multiauth in laravel](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/sboo/multiauth). in this library there are two or more type user can login in one laravel application.
In our case there are two type user **Admin** and **Public** that means User right.And you identified user by insert usertype that totally wrong my dear.

You have to use this library.just follow that link step to install library.And assign two different table  like in our case in `restaurant.com` there is user type is Public that means there is simple user that uses User table.

On another hand for admin in our case there is `restaurant.net`.This login form use admin table to login.

Both forgot password and reset password functionality works separately in one application.

```
'multi' => [ 'admin' => [ 'driver' => 'database', 'table' => 'admin', 'email' => 'client.emails.password' ], 'users' => [ 'driver' => 'database', 'table' => 'users', 'email' => 'client.emails.password', ] ],
```

Comment: There will only be one users table right? I'll check it out, does it handle restrictions to login in both Public and Admin?

Comment: yes there  are users table.yes it can absolutly restricted in both.

Comment: I'll check it out and tell you if this is what I was looking for

Comment: Will I need different auth controllers for each Public and Admin?

Comment: no not at all you have to define only two table in auth file as suggested in above library link.

Comment: 'multi' => [
            'admin' => [
                'driver' => 'database',
          
                'table' => 'admin',
                'email' => 'client.emails.password'
            ],
            'users' => [
                'driver' => 'database',
                'table' => 'users',
                'email' => 'client.emails.password',
            ]
        ],

Comment: Add it to the answer please, if there'll be only one controller how will I restrict Public to only let users type public and Admin only users type admin?

Comment: I've been reading the Docs, what i didn't understand is if i'll have to create seaprate tables for each type of user?

Comment: One of my web application I have implemented this,If you want then  I will send you gitrepo url.

Comment: Yes please, send the git repo

Comment: Ok here we go. https://github.com/jigsvirani/multiauth  ,I have also attached sql file for database

Comment: What i can see is that you repo project is under laravel 5.1, i'm currently using laravel 5... i tried to do the same into a Laravel 5 project but it doesnt work

Comment: Following the Multiauth repo instructions i don't understand if i have to make separate authcontrollers for each type of user, also separate middlewares?, i was checking your repo but it's very confusing...