# laravel- how to login with custom url address

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I try to develop my college project which i login with custom url.
For Example:

```
URL: http://localhost:8000/home_name/login



URL: http://localhost:8000/a_home/login

URL: http://localhost:8000/b_home/login

URL: http://localhost:8000/c_home/login

URL: http://localhost:8000/d_home/login
```

All homes registered on my web application which any home owner try to login then he write on url 

I explore many website but i can't find the right Solution.
Help me.

Comment: There should be one(client) or two(client, admin) URL for login. Not for everyone. You should implement logic which identifies the user role type on a login request.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933251/two-login-forms-in-laravel-5 check this

Comment: i said "If i have sachin company then he was login with sachin/login".@SachinKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a route with required parameter:

```
Route::get('/{custom}/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
```

you would only have to send the parameter to the url.

Comment: but how we get sachin from http://localhost:8000/sachin/ login

Comment: with a link: `<a href="sachin/login"> You text </a>`

Comment: To get from url to the controler: `public function youName($custom)
{
    return "This is my custom parameter: $custom";
}`